# How to get particular string from one big string ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, match

I have string 
`var str = "Ahora MXN$1,709.05"` and wanted to get only
`"MXN$1,709.05"` from this.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) or [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). With replace you are going to replace something with nothing.

**replace**

```
var str = 'Ahora MXN$1,709.05';
var sub = 'Ahora ';
var res = str.replace(sub,'');
```

**substring**

```
var str = 'Ahora MXN$1,709.05';
var sub = 'Ahora ';
var res = str.substring(sub.length);
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UbNLe/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `substring` or `Regex`

**Using substring**

```
var str = "Ahora MXN$1,709.05";
var result = str.substring('Ahora '.length);
console.log(result);
```

**Using Regex**

```
 var str = "Ahora MXN$1,709.05";
 var myRegexp = /Ahora\s(.*?)(?:\s|$)/g;
 var match = myRegexp.exec(str);
 console.log(match[1]);
```